# Dynamic Route Handling in Next.js with Server-side Rendering causing TypeError

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to implement dynamic routing in Next.js with server-side rendering, but I'm encountering an issue with TypeError. I have the following code in my pages/[id].js file:

```
``import React from 'react';

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${query.id}`);
  const post = await res.json();
  return { post };
};

export default Post;`
`
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/posts/1, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, as the post object seems to be correctly returned from the getInitialProps method. Can someone help me resolve this issue and explain what might be causing it?

Comment: Are you getting data inside `post` while doing `getInitialProps`? Also, it's a better practice to wrap your `async await` calls inside a `try {} catch {}` block and return `{post: null}` when there is an error and handle `null` condition inside the react component. e.g if `post === null` show some error message.

Comment: thank you it works now! your solution was on point (try {} catch {} block and return {post: null})

Comment: Please consider posting the solution in the comment above as an answer so that future visitors may find it useful as well!

Comment: Also with `fetch` you can check on `res.ok` like this: `if (res.ok) {} else {}` --- To see if the response succeeded.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless how do i post the solution?